# Validate input value to allow only integer and decimal value using Js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to javascript. I want to validate input box value it should allow integer and decimal value (no alphabets), no limit for integer value but for decimal value it should accept only two digit after decimal point.
https://jsfiddle.net/pnd6yvbj/
Example:

Allowed values in and decimal

```
1.1
1.12
233
```

Not allowed more than two decimal point

```
1.121
```

What I tried:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" value="" onkeyup = "check_val($(this).val())"/>

<script>
function check_val(val) {
      var val = val.replace(^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$,"");
       $("#txt").val(val.split('  ').join(' '));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The pattern should be like this to match an optional dot and 1-2 digits `^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/unspdE/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird getting error Unexpected token '^'

Comment: The pattern should be between forward slashes `val.replace(/^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/, "");`

Comment: @Thefourthbird please check jsfiddle which  https://jsfiddle.net/pnd6yvbj/  if character insert then it should replace with empty but it is not working.

Comment: This is not a good approach to sanitize string input, try `val = val.replace(/^([1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?)?.*$/, "$1");` and you will see if you type `.` anywhere in the already input value.